# OpenGL ES 2.0 lines appear more jagged than Core Animation. Is anti-aliasing possible in iOS 4?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios4, opengl-es-2.0

Is there a relatively simple way to implement anti-aliasing on **iOS 4** using **OpenGL ES 2.0**?

Had a situation where I needed to abandon **Core Animation** in favor of **OpenGL ES 2.0** to get true **3d** graphics.

Things work but I've noticed that simple **3d** cubes rendered using **Core Animation** are much crisper than those produced with **OpenGL** which have more jagged lines.

I read that **iOS 4.0** supports **anti-aliasing** for **GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP**, and I found an **[online tutorial](http://www.gandogames.com/2010/07/tutorial-using-anti-aliasing-msaa-in-the-iphone/)** (see below for code from link) that looked promising, but I have not been able to get it working.

First thing I noticed was all the **OES** suffixes which appear to be a remnant of **Open GL ES 1.0**.

Since everything I've done is for **OpenGL ES 2.0**, I tried removing every **OES** just to see what happened. Things compiled and built with zero errors or warnings but my graphics were no longer rendering.

If I keep the **OES** suffixes I get several errors and warnings of the following types:

```
Error - Use of undeclared identifier ''
Warning - Implicit declaration of function '' is invalid in C99
```

Including the **ES1** header files resulted in a clean build but still nothing got rendered. Doesn't seem like I should need to include **ES 1.0** header files to implement this functionality anyways.

**So my question is how do I get this to work, and will it actually address my issue?**

Does the approach in the online tutorial I linked have the right idea, and I just messed up the implementation, or is there a better method?

**Any guidance or details would be greatly appreciated.**

---

Code from link above:

```
GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

//Buffer definitions for the view.
GLuint viewRenderbuffer, viewFramebuffer;

//Buffer definitions for the MSAA
GLuint msaaFramebuffer, msaaRenderBuffer, msaaDepthBuffer;



//Create our viewFrame and render Buffers.
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &amp;viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &amp;viewRenderbuffer);

//Bind the buffers.
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &amp;backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &amp;backingHeight);



//Generate our MSAA Frame and Render buffers
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &amp;msaaFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &amp;msaaRenderBuffer);

//Bind our MSAA buffers
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, msaaFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaRenderBuffer);

// Generate the msaaDepthBuffer.
// 4 will be the number of pixels that the MSAA buffer will use in order to make one pixel on the render buffer.
glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_RGB5_A1_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaRenderBuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &amp;msaaDepthBuffer);

//Bind the msaa depth buffer.
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaDepthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth , backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, msaaDepthBuffer);



- (void) draw
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    //
    // Do your drawing here
    //
    // Apple (and the khronos group) encourages you to discard depth
    // render buffer contents whenever is possible
    GLenum attachments[] = {GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES};
    glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, 1, attachments);

    //Bind both MSAA and View FrameBuffers.
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, msaaFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, viewFramebuffer);

    // Call a resolve to combine both buffers
    glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();

    // Present final image to screen
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

Comment: If you are using OpenGL ES 2.0 and GLKViewController this is the way  `GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW12 is probably the modern version of what that tutorial was describing.  Multisampling wherein you draw 4 pixels that are then sampled down to 1 onscreen is the technique suggested.

Comment: Excellent advice! That link provided me EXACTLY what I needed. Took some effort to learn enough to actually understand what was going on, but that site gave a pretty direct path to the solution. Followed their steps almost exactly, just needed some knowledge to get over a few rough spots. Thanks so much.